# Can HTML DOM be used to get values from a JavaScript servlet?

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, dom, ole

I am experimenting with some browser screen scaping. Unfortunately, the webpage I am trying to get info from has multiple sources depending on where I right-click and press "view source". There is a basic desktop and a servlet that pulls data without needing to change the URL. The data that I am looking for appears in the servlet source.

I can see it as:

```
<span id="elename">value</span>.
```

I cannot get this code to work however:

```
WebPage.document.getElementByID("elename").innerHTML
```

I would appreciate any help.

EDIT: Issue is possibly due to multiple iframes?

Comment: What is `window scaping`?